# Loosing List type on abstract class implementing generic interface

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

I'm having some trouble understanding the following scenario. 
I have a "generified" interface that is implemented by an abstract class and a concrete class that extends the abstract class.

The problem is that all the methods in the abstract class returning parametrized lists have lost their type so I'm getting a compilation error telling me that it cannot convert from object to the original List type.

Could anyone provide some insight?.

In the end what I would like is to have the a getId and setId method on the abstract class having a return type of `java.lang.object`  or `<T extends Object>` and the concrete classes implementing their return type to whatever they want.

Here is the code for my different objects :

A generic interface

```
public interface MyInterface<T>{

   public T getId();
   public void setId(T id);

}
```

An abstract class implementing the interface

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass<T> implements MyInterface<T>{

  private List<String> texts;
  private List<Integer> notes;

   public List<String> getTexts(){
     return texts;
   }

   public List<Integer> getNotes(){
     return notes;
   }
}
```

A Concrete class implementing the abstract class

```
public class MyConcreteClass implements MyAbstractClass<Integer>{

    private Integer id;

    public Integer getId(){
       return this.id;
    }


    public void setId(Integer id){
          this.id = id;
    }
```

}

Some other class :

```
 public class SomeOtherClass{

   public void process(List<T extends MyAbstractClass> myClassList){

  // Compilation error -> 
  // Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String  
       for(MyAbstractClass myObj : myClassList){

            System.out.println("object Id : " + myObj.getId());

              // Compilation error -> 
              // Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String  
             for(String txt : myObj.getTexts()){


             }
       }
   }
```

}

Comment: You probably need `public void process(MyAbstractClass<Integer> myClass){`. Note the addition of **<Integer>** to the parameter type.

Comment: yeah but the thing is I want to be able to process all subtypes of my abstract class in order to call the getId() method inside the for loop. I just edited the code to better show what I'm trying to attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need another interface. See here with `MyAbstractClass` implementing two interfaces `MyInterface<T>, MyOtherInterface`.

```
  public static interface MyInterface<T> {
    public T getId();

    public void setId(T id);
  }

  public static interface MyOtherInterface {
    public List<String> getTexts();

    public List<Integer> getNotes();
  }

  public abstract class MyAbstractClass<T> implements MyInterface<T>, MyOtherInterface {
    private List<String> texts;
    private List<Integer> notes;

    public List<String> getTexts() {
      return texts;
    }

    public List<Integer> getNotes() {
      return notes;
    }
  }

  public static class MyConcreteClass extends MyAbstractClass<Integer> {
    private Integer id;

    public Integer getId() {
      return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
      this.id = id;
    }
  }

  public class SomeOtherClass {
    public void process(MyOtherInterface myClass) {

      // NO Compilation error
      for (String str : myClass.getTexts()) {
        // some processing
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: That would be almost perfect but I cannot call the getId() method within the foreach loop in the process method.. I'm starting to think that I'm not gonna be able to do this.. I slightly modified the process method to better reflect my actual code

Comment: Then it needs to be either a `MyConcreteClass` or a `MyInterface<Integer>`, unless you want to hack it with casting which would be horrible.

Comment: Yep I would rather not use casting as I agree is not very nice... I'm accepting your answer as I think is the closest one. Gosh I always get fooled by Java erasure

Answer (score 4):

When you use generic type `MyAbstractClass<T>` as raw type (`MyAbstractClass`), all generic-related stuff in declarations of its members is disabled (i.e. `List<String>` turns into `List`).

Therefore you need to declare an argument of your method as parameterized type. If you don't care about actual type parameter, use wildcard:

```
public void process(MyAbstractClass<?> myClass) { ... }
```